# Physical Links (Phys) and HDD slot

Tags: raid, webserver

We have a remote server. It has 80 HDDs and someone who is in communication with me has physical access.

I'm debugging some errors with HDDs but I only have information about the physical link (phy), I mean the software I'm using only gives me something like:

> Phy error on phy 46

Is there any way to know where this phy 46 is physically located? I mean like the slot of the HDD? I have done a research about how phys works (at least with the sas controller I'm using, is a ASR 8805 adaptec) and as I understand phys are inside of sas connectors, but it would be great if someone could give a explanation more simpler.

Comment: This is probably going to be very hardware specific. Do you have remote management access to the system (such as HP iLO or Dell iDRAC) that can give you information on specific hardware components? That may help you. You could also look at SCSI addresses for devices with system device paths using the `lsscsi` command, but you will still need to know how to map the scsi address to "phy 46". Hard to troubleshoot with limited data; this is likely going to need hardware support resources.

Comment: No, I don't have iLO or iDRAC, the only thing closer to that is BMC.

Comment: Sorry I posted the comment incomplete.

Comment: Is it an open rack (where the drives’ serial numbers are visible)? If not, do you have RAID management software? There is often an option to blink the failing drive’s LED in a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a true hardware RAID controller, so any OS-visible disk devices like `/dev/sda` would refer to RAID logical disks, not to actual physical disks. So the `dd` command suggested by stark would just blink some or possibly all disks on that RAID set.

With a hardware RAID controller, you'd need an utility from the controller vendor that can access the internal state of the RAID controller and e.g. light up/blink the light of a particular disk if it is in a hot-swap enclosure.

For the Adaptec ASR 8805, the utility in question would be "Storage Manager" and its command-line version seems to be called `arcconf`.

With it, you could get a listing of the full configuration of the RAID controller with a command like this:

```
# arcconf getconfig 1
```

(1 is the number of the Adaptec RAID controller you wish the configuration listing from, in case you have installed multiple similar controllers in the same server.)

The "phy" numbering used by the kernel may or may not be the same as the device numbering used by the `arcconf`utility, so you would need to read the configuration listing and check the listed status of each physical drive and its channel and ID numbers. Then you could blink the light of that specific disk with a command like this:

```
arcconf identify 1 device <channel> <id>
```

The command will blink the light until you press any key to stop the blinking.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this is always so hard.  I use a script to blink the disk select light.  Change sda to the name of your disk.

```
while true; do sleep 1; dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1M count=12 >/dev/null 2>&1; done
```

If the link is down, this may not work but you may be able to blink the disk next to it.

Comment: Nice workaround when `ledctl` doesn't support your hardware.